# Why webpack can't import extracted css file?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I want to generate an independent CSS file via extract-text-webpack-plugin, but it doesn't work, and the console has not reported any errors. But when I use `loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]` it work.

This is my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/js/entry.js",
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
 },
 module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')
                // loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
    ]
};
```

This is my `entry.js` file:

```
require('../css/base.css');
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: The configuration looks ok on a quick look. If you could push your a minimal test case somewhere, it would be easier to help.